# ASP.NET Display Name attribute wrong encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, attributes

Could you help me with next issue.

I have model, generated by Entity Framework, and when I try to use attribute `[Display(Name="Місто")]` in View, I see next `"Íàçâà ì³ñòà" (cp1252)`. But when I create custom model and use the same attribute, all works well.

My custom Model:

```
    public class Cities
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Місто")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Works well, in html show:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Місто</label>
```

Model generated by Entity Framework

```
    public partial class City
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public City()
    {
        this.Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
        this.Patients1 = new HashSet<Patient>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Місто")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients1 { get; set; }
}
```

Doesn't work, in html show:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">&#204;&#179;&#241;&#242;&#238;</label>
```

Can you give me any advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved, I'm just opened generated file with model in Notepad++ and encoded to utf-8